# How to use case statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i am using three query's in mysql statement using where condition
for example,how to make this as a single query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as A FROM tbl_user WHERE (b=1 AND c=0)  AND (d=1 AND e=1)
SELECT COUNT(*) as M FROM tbl_user WHERE (H=1 AND I=0)  AND (J=1 AND K=1)
```

Comment: Capslock = bad. Don't abuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `CASE` statement to do this (although it'd possibly be somewhat easier to read than using `IF` if the conditions contained `OR`s), the intent is better conveyed with an `IF`:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(b=1 AND c=0 AND d=1 AND e=1, 1, 0)) AS A,
       SUM(IF(H=1 AND I=0 AND J=1 AND K=1, 1, 0)) AS M
FROM tbl_user
```

Comment: @riz: Don't say thank you, accept one of the answers (by clicking on the check next to it).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
sum(case when (b=1 AND c=0)  AND (d=1 AND e=1) then 1 else 0 end) as CountA,
sum(case when (H=1 AND I=0)  AND (J=1 AND K=1) then 1 else 0 end) as CountM
 FROM tbl_user
```